# How to handle embedded schema in Phoenix?

Tags: mongodb, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Lets say i have `user` model like follow

```
schema "users" do
  field :user_name, :string
  field :password, :string
end
```

and `address` model like follow

```
schema "address" do
  field :line1, :string
  field :country, :string
end
```

i am using mongo db as database so i want json format like follow

> { _id: "dfd", user_name: "$$$$", password: "xxx", address: { line1 : "line1", country: "india" } }

1)how to create and validate changeset where username in `user` modal and country in `address` model are required fields?
2)how to get final changeset after validate both?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the mongo adapter works similarly to postgresql jsonb columns:

```
defmodule User do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "users" do
    field :user_name, :string
    field :password, :string
    embeds_one :address, Address
  end

  def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
    model
    |> cast(params, [:user_name, :password]
    |> cast_embed(:address)
    |> validate_required(:user_name, :password, :address)
  end
end

defmodule Address do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  @primary_key false
  embedded_schema do 
    field :line1, :string
    field :country, :string
  end

  def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
    model
    |> cast(params, [:line1, :country])
    |> validate_required([:line1, :country])
  end
end
```

Comment: `changeset.changes` looks like follow `%{user_name: "hari", password: "****", address: #Ecto.Changeset<action: :insert, changes: %{line1: "dsfsdf", country: "india"}, errors: [], data: #XXXX.Address<>, valid?: true>}` but when i try to insert am getting error like `protocol Enumerable not implemented for   #Ecto.Changeset<action: :insert, changes: %{line1: "dsfsdf", country: "india"}`

Comment: Try converting the `addess` changeset to a struct before inserting: 

cs = User.changeset(%User{}, params)

address = apply_changes(get_change(cs, :address))

cs = put_change(cs, :address, address)

Comment: it creates `_id` for embedded address document also `{
 "_id" : ObjectId("58fda5c9421aa915beeb6ff4"),
 "address" : {
  "country" : "testcountry",
  "_id" : ObjectId("58fda5c9421aa915beeb6ff3"),
  "line1" : "testline1"
 },
 "user_name" : "check",
 "password" : "******"
}
` is there any misteke i made??

Comment: My mistake. Forgot to disable the automatic primary key generation on the embedded Address schema.  Answer edited.

Comment: Now i am getting error like `schema XXXX.Address has no primary key`

Comment: @N.HariHaraSudhan did you ever get to the bottom of this problem?  I am also running into it - trying to map Ecto into an existing Mongo schema I can not alter.